# How should I respond to 404 errors in winetricks?

Tags: wine, winetricks

I am running into 404 errors using `winetricks`:

```
user@host:~$ bash winetricks gdiplus
Executing w_do_call gdiplus
Executing load_gdiplus
Executing mkdir -p /home/user/.cache/winetricks/gdiplus
Downloading http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/b/c/abc45517-97a0-4cee-a362-1957be2f24e1/WindowsXP-KB975337-x86-ENU.exe to /home/user/.cache/winetricks/gdiplus
--2012-08-10 10:29:24--  http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/b/c/abc45517-97a0-4cee-a362-1957be2f24e1/WindowsXP-KB975337-x86-ENU.exe
Resolving download.microsoft.com (download.microsoft.com)... 23.66.230.90, 23.66.230.8, 23.66.230.74, ...
Connecting to download.microsoft.com (download.microsoft.com)|23.66.230.90|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2012-08-10 10:29:24 ERROR 404: Not Found.

------------------------------------------------------
Downloading http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/b/c/abc45517-97a0-4cee-a362-1957be2f24e1/WindowsXP-KB975337-x86-ENU.exe failed
------------------------------------------------------
```

```
user@host:~$ bash winetricks tahoma
Executing w_do_call tahoma
Executing load_tahoma
Executing mkdir -p /home/user/.cache/winetricks/tahoma
Downloading http://download.microsoft.com/download/office97pro/fonts/1/w95/en-us/tahoma32.exe to /home/user/.cache/winetricks/tahoma
--2012-08-10 10:39:23--  http://download.microsoft.com/download/office97pro/fonts/1/w95/en-us/tahoma32.exe
Resolving download.microsoft.com (download.microsoft.com)... 23.66.230.81, 23.66.230.90, 23.66.230.74, ...
Connecting to download.microsoft.com (download.microsoft.com)|23.66.230.81|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2012-08-10 10:39:24 ERROR 404: Not Found.

------------------------------------------------------
Downloading http://download.microsoft.com/download/office97pro/fonts/1/w95/en-us/tahoma32.exe failed
------------------------------------------------------
```

How should I respond to these? Is there a way to get this stuff straight out of my Windows installation (dual booted)? Are there mirrors that I can point `winetricks` to in order to get these files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how you install it manually when you get a 404 error:

1. Google for the package name, here `WindowsXP-KB975337-x86-ENU.exe`
2. Download it.
3. From the terminal, simply run `wine ~/Downloads/WindowsXP-KB975337-x86-ENU.exe` (or similar) to install in your default Wine prefix.

   - You may have to click on EULAs, press one or two Next buttons, etc.; *winetricks* usually performs the quiet install.

> *Note:* you can also try updating *winetricks* to the latest bleeding-edge version [from their github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks) (`winetricks` is a script)

Comment: Awesome possum as always ;)

Answer (score 1):

Like Bruno said,

1.) Google it, also try ftp search engines (Google for them first, then search with them for that file).

2.) Download it.

Then either

3 a.) (Recommended!) Copy it to your `winetricks` cache directory in the correct subfolder.

- To do this:
  cd to `~/.cache/winetricks/`  (keep in mind that directories beginning with an . are not visible by default! If You are using `nautilus` You might try pressing Ctrl+L and entering the address manually, or, better use a console )
- There you should find the corresponding subfolder (like `crypt32` or `corefonts`). Copy your downloaded file into that subfolder. If the file already exists, overwrite it or delete it first.
- Then run `winetricks` again. Your package should now appear as "cached". Just select it, as you did the first time. Now it will install, if no other required package is missing (in which case you need to Google and copy that file, too, and run `winetricks` again).

OR

3 b.) As an alternative, you could try Bruno's way and execute the file with wine, but:

- Be sure to check the shasum of your download first, to ensure you got the right version (as there are sometimes different versions using the same filename, and to avoid manipulated files).
- Look at the scripts `winetricks` uses, some packages might not install out-of-the-box without some (wine-)tricks like Windows-version hacking.
- To do this, you need to take a look at the winetricks script (hint: try opening it with a nice text editor like `gedit`).

---

To Your Question "Is there a way to get this stuff straight out of my Windows installation (dual booted)?":
Well, theoretically, yes, but (!) keep the following in mind:

- The file version Winetricks uses is known to work. Depending on Your Windows version and architecture, Your file might, or might not work. Winetricks uses files from different windows versions.
- Winetricks sometimes uses special tricks ;-) to get things to work, like registry settings and so on. So You would need to look at the winetricks source to find out what winetricks does.
- You would need to register Your dll file override manually.
- You should be aware of potential license issues with Microsoft!

Or, the short answear to Your question: I don't think You really want to :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by replacing the gdiplus.dll inside the windows/system32 with the downloaded from this site :
http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?gdiplus
Once in the site, select the download gdiplus.zip. Unzip and extract to home/.wine/ drive_c/windows/system32.
Having done this, check by runing the winetricks,  select default winepreficks, install a windows dll or component, select gdiplus and.........should be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has released a new update for GDIPlus, therefore removing their old download link. The new file can be downloaded from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12488 - I'm not sure that this will work for Wine/Winetricks, but I'm hoping it will :D